# How to Dynamically create bootstrap columns based on user input number?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I Want to create dynamic bootstrap columns on based of user input, if user select value 1 from drop-down list, then full size col-lg-12 should visible , and if user select value from 4 input drop-down list, then col-lg-3 size four column should visible......

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend that you take the [tour] and read [ask]. Upon completion, you should provide us with a [mcve] to help us with answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to run a javascript handler on user input to add/remove the specified classes as required after the user has selected the input. If input is 4 then col-md-3, if 3 then col-md-4 and so on...

This can be done easily with jquery's [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)/[removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) functions.

Your question is very vague and to give a more specific answer is easier if you had specified your constraints.